# Will hashing both the username and the password yield any security benefits?

Tags: relational-database, security, hash, password-encryption

Will hashing both the username and the password yield any security benefits ?
I meant this scheme :

1.User enters E-mail address 

2.Calculate Hash(e-mail) address 

3.User enters password Calculate Hash(password) . 

4.Match the values to indicate a successful or failed login .

Wouldnt this make it a bit harder to match cracked hashes to the corresponding users.

I dont know if this is already used or if this idea is just impractical for some reason I havent thought of . I didnt find anything in my searches so I asked here.

Comment: If you were helped, please accept one of the answers.

Comment: You need one thing that is guaranteed unique.  A hash isn't guaranteed unique.  If you ever had the situation where two users had different emails but the same email hash, you wouldn't really be able to tell for sure which one was trying to log on.  So, it would be *less* secure.

Comment: I was thinking that the hash(username)+hash(password) combo would be unique . Now a double collision on both is still possible , like I said I was just tossing an idea.

Comment: If you did do this, you'd want to make sure you also salted the hash of the username.  Otherwise, it would be possible to precompute a dictionary (or rainbow table) that would allow quick lookup of a username given a hash.

Comment: This question would be better suited to https://security.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It would make login credentials harder to crack, but it would also mean that you wouldn't be able to get a clear text version of the user name, which is something that you may well need to do.

The best way to strengthen the security on your login credentials is to use a stronger (ie slower) salted hash algorithm on your users' passwords, such as bcrypt or PBKDF2.

See http://codahale.com/how-to-safely-store-a-password/

Comment: Hmmm .. So it would make it more secure . But it is impractical I guess .. I know about bcrypt , just asked about this wacky idea that popped into my head just now . Lets see if anyone else points out anything else.

Answer (score 2):

I'm no security expert, but it feels like it should add some security. However, you might struggle to communicate with your users that way. You can't email a hash with product updates or monthly invoices.